# How to implement Screen sharing/Remote Assist in Unity-Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm totally new to Unity-Vuforia.

I'm developing an AR app with Unity-Vuforia,in that

> ***i need to implement the screen sharing/Remote assist option between users and also screen marking feature.***

Is there any recommended features or functionalities?

Comment: Some things are unclear, do you need to do screen sharing- as in streaming your screen's video to another smartphone,
Or do you want  the state of objects on one device to be the same on other devices?

Are you using SLAM technology, or is your app only based on image tracking?
Do you have any code written already?
Please update your question accordingly and try to format your question according to StackOverflow's standards.

Comment: @MyNameIsGuzse Yes i need to stream my video to another User. I'm not aware of SLAM,my app has both Image and Model Tracking

Answer (score 0):

This will be rather difficult, as smartphones usually can't handle constantly streaming their screen without a major drop in performance. At the very least, this is not a functionality you will find in vuforia; you will have to look elsewhere.

If you are using unity, you could take a look at Droid Infinity's "Magic Screen Share", which is a plugin made for sharing android screen shots, or Google's "Google Cast Remote Display" which streams the screen to a monitor, and see if this could be a solution.